# Cannot call base_url in HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

I checked through firebug and there is an error while trying to access base_url in views/index.php. How do I fix the error?

application/site/views/index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="essential-grid-plugin-settings-css"  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/grid-plugin-settings.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--revolution slider css-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-settings-css'  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/slider/settings.css" type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='rs-plugin-inline-css'  href='css/slider/settings-inline.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--style css-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='yith-wcwl-main-css'  href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--bootstrap css-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='webuild-bootstrap-css'  href='css/bootstrap.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

site/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/masterlinkci2/';
```

index.php

```
$application_folder = 'application/site';
```

Comment: make sure you have loaded `url` helper in your `config\autoload` file , or you can manually load it in the controller like : `$this->load->helper('url');`  also tell us what error you are getting . . .

Comment: Why `$application_folder = 'application/site';`. rather it should be `$application_folder = 'application';`

Comment: I am using HMVC so I divide application into two folders site and admin.

Comment: @DYG may I suggest you watch this full tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ it's for version 2 codeigniter hmvc but still can help you with codeigniter 3 hmvc

Comment: I think there should be a way out using this way:  Here is another clue I am trying to understand someone else code that works.  He include admin folder inside the root folder where there is index.php.  $application_folder = '../application/site'; and $system_path = '../system';